# Загнать значение из поля в URL

Tags: post, php, html, get

Нужно вводимое в поле значение методом `POST` загнать в URL.

То есть, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "Найти", в URL сразу же отображалось значение, которое было введено в поле `keyword`:

```
<form action="123.php?send=<?=$_POST['keyword']?>" method="POST">
    <input name="keyword" type="text">
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Найти">
</form>
```

Comment: http://www.myfirstsite.ru/articles/get-and-post

Comment: и что? там нет конкретно того что нужно

Comment: Вам предложили уже прочитать про то, что форму можно отправлять не только методом POST, но еще и методом GET, при котором, все значения полей формы передаются в адресной строке.

Если вы напишете в форме method="GET", то после сабмита получите переход по урлу 123.php?keyword=<...>&submit=send

Comment: А какой смысл отправлять одновременно двумя способами оду и туже информацию? А сделать это не сложно. Перед оправкой узнать значения поля (используя js) и изменить атрибут "action"  для формы.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="123.php" method="GET">
```

Метод POST, заменить на GET и убрать лишнее из action="..".